# Cisco VPN IP address

Tags: ip, vpn

I've some doubts about a VPN.

I've been given a Cisco VPN client to connect to the LAN of my society. I use this to connect to a local server. I don't understand how the VPN is working.

I'm at home now. In the VPN Client I see an IP. If I go to http://www.whatismyip.com/ I see another IP, which is the IP I've when I'm also without the VPN Client, while I expected to see the IP of the VPN Client. If I use $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] I see another (third!) IP, while I expected the IP I see in the VPN Client.

Can you clarify please?

I need this to know if I'm identifies always from the same IP from the local server.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958048.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, this should be correct. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

By default you have 2 IP addresses.

1. **Local IP**: IP address used to identify yourself within your LAN.
2. **Global IP**: A public IP used to gain access to the internet. At home it will most likley be a public IP NATTED* by your ISP.

Because you're also using a VPN connection, you'll receive a third IP.

3. **Local IP for VPN**: IP address used to identify yourself on the other end of the VPN.

> *NAT = Network Address Translation

Comment: Mmm so I'll se the effects of being connected to the VPN client only when I'm browsing within the servers of the Society? I tought that VPN Client were used also to hide my IP on the internet :S

Comment: Have a look [here](http://lifehacker.com/5940565/why-you-should-start-using-a-vpn-and-how-to-choose-the-best-one-for-your-needs). From your information it seems as if you wondered what kind of IP addresses you were assigned while using a VPN connection to access your company servers.

Comment: And it's my main focus. But know I'd like to understand as much as possible :D I'm reading that link now.
So, to clarify, the server in the society's VPN will always see my as a local PC, with the local IP?

Comment: Well if you want to know as much as possible about VPN have a look on Google and check out the link I provided one comment up. But in general a VPN is used to create a tunnel on the internet. What you intend to do with it can vary.

Comment: @daimpa, yes it would be as if you were connected locally your companies LAN.

Comment: I've another question. If I make the server public (actually, after logged in via VPN I connect to the server via 10.x.x.x IP), and I assign a domain name to it, when I contact the server via the domain name, it'll see me with the IP of the VPN or with my public IP? (I can't test it)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67996/discussion-between-daimpa-and-customx).

Comment: @daimpa, so in your VPN connection you setup a remote desktop connection towards a server? If you can access the server from outside your company without using a VPN, it will see your public IP. If you access the server through the VPN it will see the IP you have from the VPN. (That's just using logic, I can't guarantee it)